# Predição de doenças cardíacas

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning

Estou tendo dificuldades na parte final, onde a saída esperada seria "paciente 1 tem cardiopatia e paciente 2 não", mas as duas afirmações são afirmativas. E está dando o seguinte erro na parte FOR: "O verdadeiro valor de um array com mais de um elemento é ambíguo. Use a.any() ou a.all() Como proceder?

```
#import the dataset

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/')
path = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Heart_Disease_Prediction.csv'

health_data = pd.read_csv (path, sep = ',')


health_data.head()
health_data.shape
health_data.info()

#replacing 'Presence' with 1 and 'Absence' with 0

health_data['Heart Disease'] = health_data['Heart Disease'].replace ({'Presence':1, 'Absence': 0})
print(health_data)

health_data.describe()

#delete the index colum (it is not necessary for this study)
health_data = health_data.drop('index', axis=1)

#remove duplicates
duplicates = health_data.duplicated()
if duplicates.any():
    print("Duplicates found!")
    duplicate_rows = health_data[duplicates]
    print(duplicate_rows)
else:
    print("No duplicates found!")

plt.figure (figsize=(12,7))
sns.heatmap(health_data.corr(), annot = True)
plt.title('Correlation between the columns')
plt.show()

#remove the collums that have real values
b_variables = health_data.iloc[:,[1,2,5,6,8,10,11,12]]
b_variables

#create subplots
num_columns = len(b_variables.columns)
num_rows = (num_columns // 2) + (num_columns % 2)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=num_rows, ncols=2, figsize=(10, num_rows * 4))

#iterate over the columns and plot count plots
for i, column in enumerate(b_variables.columns):
    row = i // 2
    col = i % 2
    sns.countplot(x=column, data=health_data, ax=axes[row, col])
    axes[row, col].set_title(f'Plot - {column}')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()


#splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
X = health_data.iloc[:, :-1] # select all columns but not the last one
y = health_data.iloc[:, -1] # select only the last colummn

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state=42)

X.shape, X_train.shape, X_test.shape
y.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape

#feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

#Logistic Regression
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
classifier = LogisticRegression()
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

#predicting the Test set results
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

#predicting the Train set results
y_pred2 = classifier.predict(X_train)

#predict probabilities
probs_y=classifier.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]

#predict probabilities
probs_y2=classifier.predict_proba(X_train)[:,1]

#accuracy test
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score, roc_curve, classification_report, accuracy_score, confusion_matrix, auc
acuracia = accuracy_score (y_test, y_pred)
print('O modelo obteve %f de acurácia.' % acuracia)

#accuracy train
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score, roc_curve, classification_report, accuracy_score, confusion_matrix, auc
acuracia = accuracy_score (y_train, y_pred2)
print('O modelo obteve %f de acurácia.' % acuracia)

#making the Confusion Matrix
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
print(cm)

#plot confusion matrix
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

ax = plt.axes()
df_cm = cm
sns.heatmap(df_cm, annot=True, annot_kws={"size": 30}, fmt='d',cmap="magma", ax = ax )
ax.set_title('Confusion Matrix')
plt.show()

#creating the ROC curve
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, probs_y)
roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(fpr, tpr, label='ROC curve (area = %0.2f)' % roc_auc)
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'k--')
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.title('ROC CURVE')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()

#building the predictive system
data_1 = (57, 1, 2, 124, 261, 0, 0, 141, 0, 0.3, 1, 0, 7) #presence
data_2 = (64, 1, 4, 128, 263, 0, 0, 105, 1, 0.2, 2, 1, 7) #absence

X = health_data.iloc[:, :-1] # select all columns but not the last one
y = health_data.iloc[:, -1] # select only the last colummn

A = health_data.iloc[:, :-1] # select all columns but not the last one
b = health_data.iloc[:, -1] # select only the last colummn

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state=42)
A_train, A_test, b_train, b_test = train_test_split(A, b, test_size = 0.25, random_state=42)

# change the input data to a numpy array
data1_array = np.asarray(data_1)
data2_array = np.asarray(data_2)

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
b_pred = classifier.predict(A_test)

probs_y=classifier.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]
probs_b=classifier.predict_proba(A_test)[:,1]

lis=[]
lis.append(probs_y)
lis.append(probs_b)

for i in range(len(lis)):
    if(lis[i] == 0):
        print("The Person",i+1,"does not have a Heart Disease\n")
    else:
        print("The Person", i+1, "has a Heart Disease\n")
```

Comment: Para evitar duplicação de orientações (seja para autor e comentaristas) o campo de comentários foi desativado aqui, mas pode ser usado na [pergunta original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/584279/70)